# Installed TCPDF and encountering PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type REPORT_PDF as array

Tags: files

I am using Drupal version 7.18 and have installed TCPDF package in my library under /var/www/html/drupal-sites/all/libraries

Everything is working well for my generated pdf report.

However, when i open /var/log/php.log on my server, i found errors which was generated everytime i click to generate the PDF report on my site:

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type REPORT_PDF as array in /var/www/html/drupal-7.18/includes/form.inc on line 799

I am not sure what is happening. It has flooded my log file.

REPORT_PDF was an object in the function:

```
$pdf = new REPORT_PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

NEW INFO AFTER CHANGING `hook_menu()` TO REMOVE `drupal_get_form()`:

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type REPORT_PDF as array in /var/www/html/drupal-7.18/modules/block/block.module on line 269

I am not sure what is happening. It has flooded my log file.

In my .module file:

```
$items['report/download/nih_pdf/%'] = array(
  'title' => NIH PDF',
  'page callback' => 'nih_pdf',
  'page arguments' => array(3),
  'file' => 'staffreport_pdf.inc',
  'access callback' => 'nih_login_access',
);
```

and in my .inc file:

function nih_pdf($arg1) {

if (!class_exists('TCPDF')) {

include_once(libraries_get_path('tcpdf') . '/tcpdf.php');
}

$pdf = new REPORT_PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('FP System');
$pdf->SetTitle('NIH Report');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('freesans', '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array('freesans', '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$txt = <<

//HTML data displayed as string

EOD;
$pdf->writeHTML($txt, true, false, false, false, '');

ob_end_clean();
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output($staff_num.'_NIH.pdf', 'D');

$pdf->Close();

return $pdf;
}

class REPORT_PDF extends TCPDF {

//Page header
 public function Header() {
 $this->SetY(15); //use in place of logo
 $this->SetFont('freesans', 'B', 16);
 $this->Cell(0, 15, 'NIH REPORT', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
 }

// Page footer
public function Footer() {
$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('freesans', 'I', 8);
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
 }
}

Hope somebody can assist. 
Thanks!

Comment: Re: your comment "REPORT_PDF" was an object," that's apparently quite true because the error message is saying that some form expects it to be an array, eg, the message "cannot use object...as [an] array," so I'd look into any custom forms you may have and see where you are be passing $pdf and it is expecting an array, not an object.  Once you find that, casting it to an array should fix things up.

Comment: any idea how can i turn off this error from logging in my log file or how do i fix my codes? My pdf function is actually stored in an INC file in one of my own developed modules, im not sure why does it concern the form.inc it is mentioning..Thanks

Comment: I had formed all my html codes inside a $txt string and use $pdf->writeHTML($txt, true, false, false, false, '');
to write into the pdf.

Comment: well, something obviously is getting the forms system involved albeit errantly.  check in your module as well as the library for any functions that might accidently follow the forms naming structure.  quick guess is something in there is named form_HOOK something or other without knowing it will be called by drupal.

Comment: i realise i am using 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 'page arguments' => array('nih_pdf'), as i need to pass in the id to retrieve the appropriate report pdf, my function is function nih_pdf($form, &$form_state) {...} is there any other way i can use so i can retrieve the id and pass it into my pdf function without using form or? my url is someting like https://xxx.xxx.xx/portal/stafflist/nih_pdf/10109_APT-CV.pdf. Thanks

Comment: the current error is based upon drupal trying to build the page and fill in all the regions that are on a normal page, eg, left, right, center, header, etc.  there must be something in your "// pdf stuff" that is passing $pdf in as the page instead of downloading the actual pdf.  Best guess without seeing it.

Comment: Hi jimajamma, i have added more info of my codes. Hope you can assist. Thanks!

Comment: the biggest issue is you are returning `$pdf` in your page callback.  Page callbacks should be returning either a render array, raw html, or numeric error codes.  I'd just return 'all done' or something similar as a first stab at further debugging.

Comment: This is very strange. When i remove return $pdf; there is no more errors logged in my log file. However, on the page itself drupal error shows: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/drupal-sites/all/libraries/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php:1155) in drupal_send_headers() (line 1216 of /var/www/html/drupal-7.18/includes/bootstrap.inc)."

Comment: Forgot to mention, my pdf still generates correctly even though i remove "return $pdf;". I guess $pdf->Output($staff_num.'_NIH.pdf', 'D'); has already send output to file hence i do not need to do a return.

Comment: that's what I figured

Comment: another issue is drupal does a lot of the ob_ buffering internally but hopefully things are getting clearer for you.

Comment: I guess its alright so long as i turn off drupal errors since every other things works well. Thanks for your help Jimajamma!